# How do I use strptime() to convert char into time structure

Tags: c, sockets, struct

Spinning my wheels to figure out how to convert a char[] to time structure. I'm reading information in from a server.c file that contains the last logged in date. Following code is the relevent code and structure.

```
typedef struct {
    char id[20];
    char firstname[30];
    char lastname[30];
    int age;
    double gpa;
    int curactive;
    char lastlogged[20];     //Format - YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS
    char tottime[15];        //Format - DDD:HH:MM:SS

struct sharedmem_struct {
    stud students[STDAMNT];


    char buffer[100];
double difference;
time_t t;
struct tm *timeptr, res;
    
//Getting current time of system
t = time (NULL);
timeptr  = localtime (&t);
    
printf("_____ Log-in Statistics _____\n");
for(int i = 0; i < STDAMNT; i++) {
    
    //copy data into buffer, convert from char to date/time, then reformat
    strcpy(buffer, z->students[i].lastlogged);
    strptime(buffer, "%x%X", &res);     
    difference = difftime(buffer, localtime);
```

The following are two warnings I'm encountering.

> main.c:129:25: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing
> 'char [100]' to parameter of type 'time_t' (aka 'long') [-Wint-conversion]
> difference = difftime(buffer, localtime);

> main.c:129:33: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing
> 'struct tm *(const time_t *)' (aka 'struct tm *(const long *)') to
> parameter of type 'time_t' (aka 'long') [-Wint-conversion]
> difference = difftime(buffer, localtime);

Using strcpy() to copy information from shared memory, and then strptime() to format it, shouldn't this convert the buffer values stored by tm? I feel I should be making use of mktime(), but am not entirely sure. Any help or relevant information would be appreciated

edit: To make things more clear. I need to use difftime() to check difference between the two dates. I'm having trouble converting the char* to a usable time_t value. Using strptime(), thought it would have been converted but I didn't do it correctly. I'm unsure where exactly went wrong.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Stuff like `difftime(buffer, localtime)` doesn't make sense. Why send in a pointer to the `localtime` function into `difftime`?

Comment: Why do you think you can pass a `char *` to `difftime`? The [difftime manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/difftime.3.html) clearly tells you what the arg types need to be so why are you even attempting that? So yes, you should use `mktime` to convert the `struct tm` to a `time_t` first.

Comment: I mean that's what he is asking about. He probably just got confused for a hot moment and didn't remember what is the input and what is the output of `strptime` and then just shoved what he thought was the output (`buffer`) into it instead of `res`. Then he gets confused by the error and isn't sure how to convert the `buffer` to what he wants and doesn't realize that, `mktime` will give him what he wants but that he would need to use it on `res`. Like it's a pretty easy mistake to make and sometimes its hard to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: As I wrote above, I understand difftime() requires two time_t  values that is a secondary issue. I'm trying to convert the char * using strptime(), but I'm not quite understanding where I went wrong in that aspect. Thank you, nathanael for helping clear that up a bit for me!

Comment: The only error you show are the compiler warnings. Which you are now saying are not really what you are primarily asking about.  So can you please clearly explain what you mean by "went wrong"? What specific error or incorrect behaviour are you actually asking about?

Comment: `time_t t2 = mktime(&res); difference = difftime(t2, t);` (no need for `localtime` variable).